# How to integrate paypal Payment Button Vuejs3 Composition API (setup function)

Tags: vue.js, paypal, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to integrate PayPal buttons with my Vuejs3 project using Composition API (setup ) but all what i get is errors i try to integrate it without using setup and its working fine i leave the working script down
the esseu is i couldent pass data from data to methodes

```
<script>
import { inject, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
export default {
 
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      paidFor: false,
      product: {
        price: 15.22,
        description: "leg lamp from that one movie",
        img: "./assets/lamp.jpg",
      },
    };
  },
   setup() {
    const store = inject("store");
    console.log(store.state.prodects_in_cart);
    return { store };
  },methods:{
     setLoaded: function() {
      this.loaded = true;
     paypal_sdk
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  description: this.product.description,
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: this.product.price
                  }
                }
              ]
            });
          },
          onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();
            this.data;
            this.paidFor = true;
            console.log(order);
          },
          onError: err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        })
        .render(this.$refs.paypal);
    }
    
  },
  mounted: function() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
     script.setAttribute('data-namespace',"paypal_sdk");
    script.src ="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Here i pute my Client Id";
    script.addEventListener("load", this.setLoaded);
   
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  },
};
</script>
```

the error i get when i use setup() is
[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn0yu.png)

my script using setup()

```
 setup() {
    const store = inject("store");
    const paypal = ref(null);
    let loaded = ref(false);
    let paidFor = ref(false);

    const product = {
      price: 15.22,
      description: "leg lamp from that one movie",
      img: "./assets/lamp.jpg",
    };

    onMounted: {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.setAttribute("data-namespace", "paypal_sdk");
      script.src =
        "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AXDJPmFjXpXm9HMXK4uZcW3l9XrCL36AxEeWBa4rhV2-xFcVYJrGKvNowY-xf2PitTSkStVNjabZaihe";
      script.addEventListener("load",  ()=>{
          loaded = true;
       console.log('hello adil');
      paypal_sdk
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: (data, actions) => { 
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  description: 'this is product description',
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: 120.00,
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          },
          onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();
            this.data;
            this.paidFor = true;
            console.log(order);
          },
          onError: (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          },
        })
        .render(paypal);
      });
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    return { store ,paypal};
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `paypal` is a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref). You're currently passing to `paypal_sdk` the `ref` itself and not the inner value, which would be the template ref's element. To fix this, pass the `ref`'s `.value`.
2. Your `onMounted` code is not properly invoked, as it must be passed a callback.

```js
import { onMounted, ref }  from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const paypal = ref(null)

    onMounted(/* 2 */ () => {
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      //...
      script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        paypal_sdk
          .Buttons(/*...*/)
          .render(paypal.value) /* 1 */
      })
    })

    return {
      paypal
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that error is because you are using option Api onMounted life cycle hook, instead of doing that use the vue 3 life cycle hooks for onMounted.

First you will have to import it from vue like this.

```html
<script>
import {onMounted} from 'vue'

then you are going to use it like this.
return it as a call back function

onMounted(() => {
    //all your code should placed inside here and it will work
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer using the [paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/paypal-js) npm package

```
<template>
  <div ref="paypalBtn"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { loadScript } from '@paypal/paypal-js';

const paypalBtn = ref(null);

onMounted(async () => {
  let paypal;

  try {
    paypal = await loadScript({
      'client-id': 'you_client_id_goes_here',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('failed to load the PayPal JS SDK script', error);
  }

  if (paypal) {
    try {
      await paypal.Buttons().render(paypalBtn.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('failed to render the PayPal Buttons', error);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```